# Notice: Undefined offset: 0 - PHP - Foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, undefined

I am creating a calendar for one of my sites, I have an array as follows.

```
array(2) {
[2017]=> array(1) {
    ["01"]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> object(stdClass)#5374 (4) {
            ["ID"]=> string(3) "409"
            ["data"]=> string(10) "01/01/2017"
            ["post_title"]=> string(5) "TESTE"
            ["guid"]=> string(71) "?post_type=todos_os_cursos&p=409" 
        }
    }
}

[2016]=> array(2) {
    [10]=> array(2) {
        [0]=> object(stdClass)#5974 (4) {
            ["ID"]=> string(3) "153"
            ["data"]=> string(10) "19/10/2016"
            ["post_title"]=> string(23) "Mundi Chef Professional"
            ["guid"]=> string(71) "?post_type=todos_os_cursos&p=153" }

        [1]=> object(stdClass)#5977 (4) {
            ["ID"]=> string(3) "145"
            ["data"]=> string(10) "01/10/2016"
            ["post_title"]=> string(30) "Mundi Confeiteiro Professional"
            ["guid"]=> string(71) "?post_type=todos_os_cursos&p=145"
        }
    }

    ["09"]=> array(4) {
        [0]=> object(stdClass)#5978 (4) {
            ["ID"]=> string(3) "153"
            ["data"]=> string(10) "30/09/2016"
            ["post_title"]=> string(23) "Mundi Chef Professional"
            ["guid"]=> string(71) "?post_type=todos_os_cursos&p=153"
        }
    }
}

[....]
```

I need to organize this as a calendar. For example.

Year
-- Month
-- -- the items
-- Month
-- -- the items

Year [...]

But I'm not getting. Every time I try to access the items always have the same problem. Notice: Undefined offset.

Comment: You should show the code that caused the undefined offset error. *hint* the error message tells  you on what line the error occurred. Include relevant code (i.e. the surrounding loop) that would help demonstrated the problem to the reader.

Comment: i really hope your making sure that when you access months bellow 10 you are still using strings to access them because [`array[9]` is not the same as `array["09"]`](http://www.tehplayground.com/#iryv4NZhl). just a concern seeing how you don't make 10 as a string

Answer (score 0):

I'm goign to take a stab in the dark with the lack of proper code in your question and assume this error is being caused when you try and do `array[09]` to access your `array("09" => array())`. these wont work because 09, and 08 = 0.

why? this is because when you prefix an integer with 0 it's no longer a [decimal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal) which is base 10 (0-9) but an [Octal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) which is base 8 (0-7)

take the [following code](http://www.tehplayground.com/#0cqvC0qwT)

```
$myarr = array(0 => 16, 9 => 12, "09" => 51);

var_dump(09);
var_dump($myarr[09]);
```

as you can see when we `var_dump(09)` the result is int(0) because 08 and 09 are invalid in the octal number system. so when we go `$myarr[09]` we are actually going `$myarr[0]` and then we get the value under the 0 key.

your Undefined offset 0 notice is most likely because of this, the 09 = int(0) so your trying to access a value in the array which is undefined.

also, to reiterate my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39501110/notice-undefined-offset-0-php-foreach#comment66319731_39501110), `array[9]` is not the same as `array["09"]` but `array[10]` is the same as `array["10"]`. [example](http://www.tehplayground.com/#iryv4NZhl)

```
$mayarr = array("09"=>22);
var_dump($mayarr);
var_dump($mayarr[9]);

$mayarr = array("09"=>22, 9=>106, 10=> 3, "10"=> 50);
var_dump($mayarr);
var_dump($mayarr[9]);
var_dump($mayarr[10]);
var_dump($mayarr["10"]);
```

if your going to use numerals as keys you should really be consistent, integer or string